# Dynamically loading an Automator action based on a filename

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to create an Automator action that will load an external Automator action based on a portion of a filename, on folder drag.

For example:

Filename[Type1].xxx
Filename[Type2].xxx
Filename[Type3].xxx

Type 1 - 3 will run a specified automator tailored for that file.  Is this at all possible?

Comment: Is it always going to follow the pattern of containing a bracket then the word type then a number then a bracket?

Comment: Why not just contain all the Automator scripts in one? Why\ does it need to load an external one?

Comment: @Jbis Not necessarily. There may be additional suffixes and strings within the filename depending on the situation.

Comment: @JustinKok So what will be the format.

Comment: @JMY1000 Because each Automator is quite lengthly, I figured it would be a good way to keep things 'cleaner' in a way.  Essentially, I'm looking to output a batch of responsive images from a folder in a few dimensions, but the dimensions are dependant on what kind of file it is.

Comment: @JBis [xxx]_[a]_[DEFINING STRING]_[xxx]_[optional suffix]_[width]x[height].jpg

Comment: @JustinKok So you want `[width]x[height]` to be the crop size?

Comment: @JBis Actually, the width and height are processed by the external automators. My mistake, the string is actually: [xxx]_[a]_[DEFINING STRING]_[xxx]_[optional suffix].jpg

Comment: @JustinKok Are brackets there or just placeholders for examples?

Comment: @JBis No brackets, just placeholders! (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Alright I'll build it for you. Probably post tonight.

Comment: IMO Your question, as is, is poorly written! It is not totally clear what it is you're trying to accomplish. Automator has no way of performing an action based solely on "folder drag". If you are actually referring to dragging and dropping Finder items onto an Automator application, then you should clearly and plainly state this. You should also include real world examples of the before and after of what you're trying to accomplish as well as showing what Automator actions are already involved!

Answer (score 1):

Save the following script as an application. Copy and paste into Script Editor (not automator):

```
on open myItems
    set ds to {"file1", "file2", "file3"} # Enter identifiyers
    set scriptlocation to {"dothis.app", "imeanthis.app", "PleaseUpvoteMy.app} # Enter scripts location as POSIX path, respectivly
    repeat with myItem in myItems
        tell application "Finder"
            set theName to the name of (myItems as alias)
        end tell
        set rptvly to getIndex of theName of ds
        do shell script "open " & the quoted form of rptvly
    end repeat
end open




to getIndex of i from l
    repeat with n from 1 to count l
        if (i as string) contains ((l's item n) as string) then return n
    end repeat
    0
end getIndex
```

**Comment any errors as I am on Mojave beta and having issue where I cannot run sccripts**

Comment: LMAO... "PleaseUpvoteMy.app" . ... Brilliant Absolutely Brilliant

Comment: @wch1zpink :) :)